# Handling expensive task(nested for loop) on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

First I write summarized pseudo code.

```
const ExcelSheet = new ExcelSheet() // excel.js library

const usersWithPlayedGames  = await findAllUsers({ include: GameTable });

for (let i = 0; i < usersWithPlayedGames.length; i++) {
    // Write some user data on Excel.
    ...
    ...
    for (let j = 0; j < usersWithPlayedGames[i].length; j++) {
        // Write some user's game on Excel
        ...
        ...
        for (let k = 0; k < usersWithPlayedGames[i][j].length; k++) {
            // Write some users's game's company data on Excel
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}

res.send(ExcelSheet.toFile());
```

The actual code is pretty long.

And it take client req => res time almost 15sec.

I know my problem solution is not good.

I can do refactoring with this code.

But the real problem is it blocks another client request.

I search on google and find several solutions.

1. Node.js child process spawn.
2. Make with a callback function(I don't know exactly how to do).
3. Write more than a good algorithm.

What's the concept I'm missing from Node.js?

Please help me with a small favor.

Thank you.

Comment: `Write some user data on Excel.`, `Write some user's game on Excel` and  `Write some users's game's company data on Excel` .... is there an asynchronous way of doing these? Since you haven't shown this code its hard to guess ... but that would solve the `blocks another client request` issue

Comment: @Bravo Thank you but I can't find with excel.js library async method.

Comment: There are some, but perhaps the refactoring from your current code is going to be too difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're porbably better off running this in a child process or somewhere else outside your web request thread, but if that's not an option, you could break the task up using something like `setImmediate`

```
const ExcelSheet = new ExcelSheet() // excel.js library

const usersWithPlayedGames  = await findAllUsers({ include: GameTable });

const excelLoop = (index) => {

  for (let j = 0; j < usersWithPlayedGames[index].length; j++) {
      // Write some user's game on Excel
      ...
      ...
      for (let k = 0; k < usersWithPlayedGames[index][j].length; k++) {
          // Write some users's game's company data on Excel
          ...
          ...
      }
  }

  if (index < usersWithPlayedGames.length) {
    setImmediate(() => excelLoop(index + 1))
  }
  else {
    res.send(ExcelSheet.toFile());
  }
};

excelLoop(0);
```

[Documentation for setImmediate](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will follow your link